# Firebase Auth on Web - How to add spam protection for email/password login

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

For my website, I want to build my own login form for email/password based authentication using Firebase authentication instead of using FirebaseUI Web. I'll be using createUserWithEmailAndPassword JS function to create new user accounts. But how can I prevent spam registrations? Usually for web based forms, I would use Google Recaptcha and validate the recaptcha on my server. But here, I'm not using my server for creating the user accounts. I'm making a call on the client side to create the user accounts.

Of course, I'll be using email verification in the flow, but how would I prevent bots from creating the accounts in the first place?

I also understand that Firebase has some sort of limit for the number of requests per min from a single IP, but I would like to go further and try to prevent those registrations.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

After 2 years, this question is still valid and as far as I see, it is not possible. You probably do not need an answer to this question anymore but it may help others. Even if you succeed in doing something manually, those js functions will stay there and can be called manually by any user who knows how to do it.

If there are no hidden, top secret options which are not available in the documentation, this is not possible. There is a recaptcha option but it is only for Phone Authentication. So, it seems like you have 2 options.

1. Ignore and delete users who do not verify their email address.
2. Disable email option from Firebase console and implement your own
   email authentication. Generate your own token and log user into
   Firebase with that custom token. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth

Answer (score 2):

I'm following up on frankish's answer. He is totally correct, and I agree I think it's strange that Firebase automatically integrates ReCaptcha when doing phone authentication (and now when doing Phone MFA), but does not provide support in `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` for passing a recaptcha verifier. Thus, the only way to really get around this is to do something like the following:

1. Set up ReCaptcha (either V2 or V3) manually on your signup page. Do NOT use `firebase. auth. RecaptchaVerifier`, that is only for integration with phone authentication.
2. Immediately after calling `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, you need to make a call to your own server that passes up the recaptcha token. There is a Firebase blog post here about how to do that with a Firebase Function: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/08/guard-your-web-content-from-abuse-with.html. Note I think it's a bit strange that Firebase documented how to do this with server-side functions but didn't directly integrate this with account creation.
3. The final point is that in your server-side code, after you make the call to validate the recaptcha token, you need to set a custom claim on the Firebase user with the Firebase Admin API. That claim can be something like `recaptchaPassed: true` (or false). For details on custom claims see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims.

After that, you can then do things based on the value of that custom claim. For example you could read that custom claim in other server-side calls, or you can use it in Firestore security rules (good blog post on this, https://medium.com/google-developers/controlling-data-access-using-firebase-auth-custom-claims-88b3c2c9352a). You could also choose to immediately delete the user server-side (using the admin API), if recaptcha verification fails.

Note it's important to understand that there is nothing that guarantees that some malicious script will call your server-side token verification function after the code on the client calls `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`. Thus, the only way the rest of your code can guarantee that a particular Firebase user passed recaptcha verification is by looking for your custom claim that you set on the user server-side.